# NX Serve is not loading Ignite UI Theme

Tags: angularjs, nomachine-nx, ignite-ui-angular

When I try to run npx nx server ignite-theme then it's not loading my ignite theme and throwing Can't find stylesheet to import.

I have changed NX versions and also try to same version of IgniteUi Angular but getting same error.

My node version is v20.10.0
NX workspace 16.5.0
Angular  version 16.2.0